# Java abstract method with generic argument

Tags: java, generics, abstract, extends

I have the following situation: There is abstract Class (`abs`) and two classes which extend from `abs` (`con1` and `con2`)

Now I want abs to have an abstract function with an argument where the type of the argument has to be the type of the class itself.

I tried the following in the `abs` class:

```
public abstract void foo(abs i);
```

and the following in `con1` and `con2`:

```
public abstract void foo(con1 i);
public abstract void foo(con1 i);
```

but this didn't work. What is the general method to solve problems like that?

Comment: "this didnt work" is never enough information. Rather than just describing the problem, you should give a short but complete example demonstrating it, and include the exact error message you got.

Answer (score 2):

No, basically that doesn't implement the method. With the declarations you've got, I *should* be able to write:

```
abs x = new con1();
abs y = new con2();
x.foo(y);
```

It sounds like you want:

```
public abstract class Abstract<T extends Abstract<T>>
{
    public abstract void foo(T t);
}
```

Then:

```
public final class Concrete1 extends Abstract<Concrete1>
{
    @Override public void foo(Concrete1 x) { ... }
}
```

Note that this doesn't completely enforce it, as you could still write:

```
public final class Evil extends Abstract<Concrete1>
```

... but it at least works when everyone's "playing by the rules".

Comment: Thanks Jon for the answer. You said you should be able to write                  abs x = new con1();
abs y = new con2();
x.foo(y);  where this should be illegal in my setting. And "public final class Concrete1 extends Abstract<Concrete1>" sounds very redundant to me. But if this the only solution I will take that approach. Thank you :)

Comment: @DanielRoss: With the way you described the code in your question, yes. That *wouldn't* be the case with the code I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

The method definition should be the same on con1 and con2:

```
@override
public abstract void foo(abs i)
{ ...
```

Here the annotation check that you are really overriding the parent here. Google "inheritance and polymorphism"